# Can we type cast in generic list?

Tags: list, c#-3.0

Can we typecast in generic list like creating list in string and trying to add and retrieve  int value... e.g:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add("prakash");
    list.Add("arun");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want? What number should be added, when you add "prakash"?

Comment: If you need list of objects of different types, you can use `List<Object> list = new List<Object>();`

Comment: yes but my question is i have a generic list with int datatype can we add string values in the list using typecasting.

Comment: No, you can not cast string to int. However you can use `int.Parse()` method if your string represents a number.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add a string to a generic `List<int>`.  As Dmitry pointed out you can try parsing strings to `int` before adding them.

You can use an if statement with TryParse as seen below.

```
int theNumber;
if (int.TryParse("prakash", out theNumber))
{
    list.Add(theNumber);//Will not be added 
}

if (int.TryParse("42", out theNumber))
{
    list.Add(theNumber);//Will be added
}
```